# What are the state-of-the-art cell-type RNA-Seq deconvolution methods?

Tags: rna-seq, gene-expression, machine-learning

I would like to find the proportion of each cell-type in bulk RNA-Seq transcriptomics data. I am looking for some guidance on the following:

- What are the state-of-the-art methods?
- What are their assumptions? (e.g. do they assume that cell-type expression signatures are available in advance?)

Comment: Can you describe your experimental design further? This is often solved with single cell RNA-seq

Comment: It's not my experiment - I am just trying to deconvolve bulk RNA-Seq data from a publicly available database (GTEx), e.g. given a whole blood sample, find out the proportions of each cell type (e.g. lymphocytes, macrophages,...). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people using xCell. There should also be papers systematically compare many different methods, which might interest you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Do you have any reference of a good up-to-date review paper? A simple description of the methods and requirements would be highly appreciated too

Comment: This one looks promising although it may not cover all the methods https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.01.10.897116v1.full.pdf